# Comparing an existing file with the result of a heavy process using named pipes

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to figure out a way to compare an existing file with the result of a process (a heavy one, not to be repeated) and clobber the existing file with the result of that process without having to write it in a temp file (it would be a large temp file, about the same size of the existing file: let's try to be efficient and not take twice space it should).

I would like to replace the normal file `/tmp/replace_with_that` (see below) with a fifo, but of course doing so with the code below would just lock up the script, since the `/tmp/replace_with_that` fifo cannot be read before comparing the existing file with the named pipe `/tmp/test_against_this`

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/test_against_this
: > /tmp/replace_with_that    

echo 'A B C D' >/some/existing/file

{
  #A very heavy process not to repeat;
  #Solved: we used a named pipe.
  #Its large output should not be sent to a file
  #To solve: using this code, we write the output to a regular file

  for LETTER in "A B C D E"  
  do  
      echo $LETTER      
  done  

} | tee /tmp/test_against_this /tmp/replace_with_that >/dev/null &  

if cmp -s /some/existing/file /tmp/test_against_this
then  
    echo Exact copy
    #Don't do a thing to /some/existing/file
else
    echo Differs
    #Clobber /some/existing/file with /tmp/replace_with_that
    cat /tmp/replace_with_that >/some/existing/file
fi  

rm -f /tmp/test_against_this  
rm -f /tmp/replace_with_that
```

Comment: Why can't you just `heavy_process > /some/existing/file`? The end result would be the same.

Comment: FWIW - /tmp/filename may not not necessarily be a physical file on disk. You do not mention the actual OS, but Solaris and Linux will use RAM or ramdisk or kernel memory for storing files written to /tmp.  The overhead of writing to and reading from memory is generally very small.

Comment: @that other guy: I should have stated that /some/existing/file should not be modified in any way if it's the exact copy of what is produced.  If it's a copy and we clubber it, mtime for instance is changed, and maybe some other properties I don't know about.  I could of course try to get the full state of that file before clubbering, and then patch that state on it after clubbering, but I was looking for another more elegant way...

Comment: @jim mcnamara: I'm dealing with virtualized Linux envs, which is another way to say: can I access that, or this, or will I be hit on the nose in some other interesting way by writing large files to directories (like /temp) that are not under my exclusive control.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with 20GB (or some other large number)  files, things should be okay.  This is more of a syadmin problem, configuring & allocating RAM properly for the load.  See what free tells you. Note: you can use the utime() system call to change file times easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness, my answer (wanted to explore the use of pipes):

Was trying to find a way to compare on the fly a stream and an existing file, without overwriting the existing file unnecessarily (leaving it as is if stream and file are exact copies), and without creating sometimes big temp files (the product of a a heavy process like mysqldump for instance).  The solution had to rely on pipes only (named and anonymous), and maybe a few very small temp files.

The checksum solution suggested by twalberg is just fine, but md5sum calls on large files are processor intensive (and processing time lengthens linearly with file size).  cmp is faster.

Example call of the function listed below:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkfifo /tmp/fifo

mysqldump --skip-comments $HOST $USER $PASSWORD $DB >/tmp/fifo &

create_or_replace /some/existing/dump /tmp/fifo

#This also works, but depending on the anonymous fifo setup, seems less robust

create_or_replace /some/existing/dump <(mysqldump --skip-comments $HOST $USER $PASSWORD $DB)
```

The functions:

```
#!/bin/bash

checkdiff(){
    local originalfilepath="$1"
    local differs="$2"
    local streamsize="$3"
    local timeoutseconds="$4"
    local originalfilesize=$(stat -c '%s' "$originalfilepath")
    local starttime
    local stoptime

    #Hackish: we can't know for sure when the wc subprocess will have produced the streamsize file
    starttime=$(date +%s)
    stoptime=$(( $starttime + $timeoutseconds ))
    while ([[ ! -f "$streamsize" ]] && (( $stoptime > $(date +%s) ))); do :; done;

    if ([[ ! -f "$streamsize" ]] || (( $originalfilesize == $(cat "$streamsize" | head -1) )))
    then
        #Using streams that were exact copies of files to compare with,
        #on average, with just a few test runs:
        #diff slowest, md5sum 2% faster than diff, and cmp method 5% faster than md5sum
        #Did not test, but on large unequal files,
        #cmp method should be way ahead of the 2 other methods
        #since equal files is the worst case scenario for cmp

        #diff -q --speed-large-files <(sort "$originalfilepath") <(sort -) >"$differs"
        #( [[ $(md5sum "$originalfilepath" | cut -b-32) = $(md5sum - | cut -b-32) ]] && : || echo -n '1' ) >"$differs" 
        ( cmp -s "$originalfilepath" - && : || echo -n '1' ) >"$differs"
    else
        echo -n '1' >"$differs"
    fi
}

create_or_replace(){

    local originalfilepath="$1"
    local newfilepath="$2" #Should be a pipe, but could be a regular file
    local differs="$originalfilepath.differs"
    local streamsize="$originalfilepath.size"
    local timeoutseconds=30
    local starttime
    local stoptime

    if [[ -f "$originalfilepath" ]]
    then
        #Cleanup
        [[ -f "$differs" ]] && rm -f "$differs"
        [[ -f "$streamsize" ]] && rm -f "$streamsize"

        #cat the pipe, get its size, check for differences between the stream and the file and pipe the stream into the original file if all checks show a diff
        cat "$newfilepath" |
        tee >(wc -m - | cut -f1 -d' ' >"$streamsize") >(checkdiff "$originalfilepath" "$differs" "$streamsize" "$timeoutseconds") | {

                #Hackish: we can't know for sure when the checkdiff subprocess will have produced the differs file
                starttime=$(date +%s)
                stoptime=$(( $starttime + $timeoutseconds ))
                while ([[ ! -f "$differs" ]] && (( $stoptime > $(date +%s) ))); do :; done;

                [[ ! -f "$differs" ]] || [[ ! -z $(cat "$differs" | head -1) ]] && cat - >"$originalfilepath"
        }

        #Cleanup
        [[ -f "$differs" ]] && rm -f "$differs"
        [[ -f "$streamsize" ]] && rm -f "$streamsize"

    else
        cat "$newfilepath" >"$originalfilepath"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I would recommend a different approach:

1. Generate an MD5/SHA1/SHA256/whatever hash of the existing file
2. Run your heavy process and replace the output file
3. Generate a hash of the new file
4. If the hashes match, the files were the same; if not, the new file is different

Comment: It's worth noting that if you replace the output file using `heavy_process > file`, all file attributes will be retained as the file is overwritten in place (except file access times which can be set with `touch`).

Comment: @twalberg: Doesn't that approach add to the processing time instead of limiting it, if you compare it to the code above?

Comment: @that other guy  Did not know that. That behavior is consistant across *nix systems?  If it is, I'll forget my pipe dreams :-)

Comment: @FranklinC.James It would add some CPU overhead for calculating the hash. But those CPU cycles would likely be hidden by the I/O latencies, so may not be noticeable - depends on how big the file is. If that proves to be a concern, choosing the hash function that uses the least CPU power yet still gives a sufficient guarantee of detecting a difference would be good.

Comment: @that other guy: Glad I came across what you mentioned about file attributes not changing.  I'm using tar to build incremental archives, and the mtime NEEDS to change if the file is indeed different from the process output. I will need to touch it, otherwise tar will just ignore it...  Not good...  So my test using a pipe seems more valid.  Sorry I did not talked about the time attributes, tar, etc.  The question would have been better,

Comment: @FranklinC.James To get around the mtime issue, you can add step 1a) `touch -r existing_file /tmp/junkfile_to_record_existing_mtime` and step 5) If the file didn't change, `touch -r /tmp/junkfile_to_record_existing_mtime existing_file`. That saves the existing mtime and copies it back if appropriate.

Comment: @FranklinC.James Overwriting the existing file is implied by POSIX, and it's what bash does on any OS.